# Current HSTS set not displaying visited sites

Tags: hsts

I'm using `chrome://net-internals/#hsts` to do HSTS testing.

I tried to query a domain that has HST preloaded (facebook.com), and got the expected results:

**Found:**
static_sts_domain: facebook.com

However, I tried the following steps with a domain that is not preloaded (live.com)

1. Go to http://live.com (I then get redirected to https://live.com)
2. Query live.com domain for HSTS (using `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`) 
   Results: 
   **Not found**
3. Go to https://live.com (directly typing HTTPS to avoid being redirected)
4. Query live.com domain for HSTS (using `chrome://net-internals/#hsts`) 
   Results: 
   **Found:**
   dynamic_sts_domain: live.com

I don't understand why my query at step 2 didn't find anything. I got redirected, but I ultimately visited https://live.com and received a response that contained an HSTS header `Strict-Transport-Security:max-age=63072000;includeSubDomains`.

Comment: see: https://superuser.com/a/1235540/60046